# Bash - Execute command with output displaying and then grep it for a summary (pull all git repos)

Tags: linux, bash, git

I got a oneliner as a command to pull all git repos in a directory.
But at the end I would like some sort of summary displaying all errors.

I've already gotten quite far:

```
cd ~/bitbucket; \
find . \
    -maxdepth 2 -type d \
    -name ".git" \
    -execdir python3 -c 'import os; print("\33[33m----------------------------------------------  " + os.path.abspath(".") + "  ----------------------------------------------\33[0m")' \; \
    -execdir git checkout development \; \
    -execdir git branch \; \
    -execdir git pull \; \
    -execdir git status \; \
    -execdir echo \; \
    -execdir echo \; \
| grep -i -e "^" -e "error"
```

This will go into the right dir and for each git repo it will do all the git stuff and highlight the word error.
2 issues I have left are the output coloring from git is gone (for example from the git branch command) and the errors aren't displayed at the end.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: The default setup for Git is that most user-oriented commands, like `git branch`, colorize their output if and only if it is going to a "tty" (something for which `isatty(3)` returns true. You can force them to colorize their output even if it's not, using various `-c` options. However, it's almost always a bad idea to use user-facing commands from a script in the first place. I'd recommend just having (or building) a list of Git repositories as one item, and using `git fetch` as the automated action. Leave any merging or rebasing (the extra step that `git pull` does) to a user.

Comment: You'll end up with one script to update the list of repositories, and a `cron` task or similar to run `git fetch` in all of them. Git is currently growing a maintenance suite of commands that are designed to make this easier, so you'll be able to switch to using the official Git version of this when it comes out.

Comment: It seems likely that the errors you are trying to capture are going to be on stderr, so they aren't going into the pipe to grep at all.  You probably want `find >&2 ... | grep`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `-e "^"`?

Comment: @torek The dev branches are kind of like the master. We create branches from them, so I'll never do actual changes to it. Otherwise I would totally agree with your explanation :) This command is just to get all latest releases as the repos are fast changing. Do you have a link or something to the new to be released git suite? I'm curious :)

Comment: @WilliamPursell Capturing every line, otherwise it'd only get the lines containing error.

Comment: A link: no; a search query: yes: https://www.google.com/search?q=git+maintenance+commands+public-inbox.org (well, also, one direct link: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance)